# When autowiring use would be beneficiary with example

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have recently learned concept of autowiring in spring. When I was trying to understand in which particular scenarios spring autowiring can be useful 
I came up with the below two reasons from one of the questions asked in our stakoverflow forum.

1.I wanted to read values from a property file and inject them into a bean. Only way I could figure out how to do this at start up of my app was to 
wire the bean in XML (and inject the properties.) I ended up using the "byName" attribute (because the bean was also marked as `@Component`) and then 
used `@Autowired` `@Qualifier("nameIChose")` when injecting the bean into another class. It's the only bean I've written that I wire with XML.

2.I've found autowiring useful in cases where I've had a factory bean making another bean (whose implementation class name was described in a system 
property,so I couldn't define the all wiring in XML). I usually prefer to make my wiring explicit though;

Can any body please give me some code snippet example of the above situations that would make my understanding of autowiring more clearer?

Comment: Autowiring is useful any time you prefer no XML at all to a gigantic, type-unsafe, cumbersome to edit and maintain, XML file.

Comment: @Nizet Thanks for the answer. But are there any specific scenarios where the usage of the autowiring would be very useful.Since I am new to spring I am just trying to understand where would be more useful to use autowiring.

Comment: That's not how you should see it. You should see it as the default, simplest way of doing things for 99% of the bean declarations and injections, but which must be replaced by Java config (or XML, but XML really sucks) in the remaining 1% where autowiring is not sufficient.

Comment: @Nizet Don't get me wrong on this. But I attended interview few days back where they asked me this question. What are the scenarios where the autowiring is necessary or beneficiary? So what should be appropriate answer for that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of injecting properties into a bean.

Using field injection:

```
@Component
public class YourBean {

    @Value("${your.property.name}")
    private String yourProperty;
}
```

Using constructor injection:

```
@Component
public class YourBean2 {

    private String yourProperty;

    @Autowired
    public YourBeans2(@Value("${your.property.name}") String yourProperty) {
       this.yourProperty = yourProperty;
    }
}
```

The following is a super simple example of autowiring various beans

```
@Component
public class Foo {

    public void doSomething() {

    }
}

@Component
public class Bar {

   private Foo foo;

   @Autowired
   public Bar(Foo foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
   }

   public void doSomethingElse() {
      foo.doSomething();
   }
}
```

In the previous example, no XML configuration of Foo and Bar needs to be done, Spring automatically picks up the beans because of their `@Component` annotation (assuming of course that component scanning has been enabled)

Comment: @Is it comuplosry to use the autowiring when we want to map the properties of the bean to properties file ?

Comment: What do you mean map the properties a bean to a properties file?

Comment: what i mean is i have a properties file which contain set of properties and I have a bean which has set of attributes. I want to set the values written inside the property file to the attributes of the bean.

Comment: @Beast Ok, I see what you mean. You could of course use `@Value` for each property, but for a more general way to do it, I would suggest `@ConfigurationProperties` from Spring Boot